# Will resetting an application pool automatically close all database connections?

Tags: iis-6, database-connection, reset, application-pool

I am running IIS6.0. I have the `DefaultAppPool` running one website.

If I reset this application pool would that automatically close all database connections that are being used by the website?

hope that makes sense, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, refreshing the application pool will fundamentally restart your application and re-establish all your database connections.